# How to use post in corda api instaed of put?

Tags: corda

**How do you use post in corda api? Instead of using the put method can we use post?

Like the @PUT is there any option for @POST**

```
 @PUT
 @Path("create-iou")
 fun createIOU(@QueryParam("iouValue") iouValue: Int, 
      @QueryParam("partyName") partyName: CordaX500Name?): 
      Response {
            if (iouValue <= 0 ) {
                return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Query parameter 'iouValue' must be non-negative.\n").build()
            }
            if (partyName == null) {
                return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Query parameter 'partyName' missing or has wrong format.\n").build()
            }
            val otherParty = rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyName) ?:
                    return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Party named $partyName cannot be found.\n").build()

            return try {
                val signedTx = rpcOps.startTrackedFlow(::Initiator, iouValue, otherParty).returnValue.getOrThrow()
                Response.status(CREATED).entity("Transaction id ${signedTx.id} committed to ledger.\n").build()

            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                logger.error(ex.message, ex)
                Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(ex.message!!).build()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply change the annotation to `@POST`:

```
@PUT
@Path("create-iou")
fun createIOU(@QueryParam("iouValue") iouValue: Int, 
    @QueryParam("partyName") partyName: CordaX500Name?): Response {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("create-iou")
fun createIOU(@FormParam("iouValue") iouValue: Int...
```

The solution of changing only the annotation to `@POST` did not work for me and gave me this exception:

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Parameter specified as non-null is null